# Best framework for creating desktop applications with dynamic GUI

Tags: user-interface, frameworks

Sorry for the unusual question, but I don't know where else to ask this.
Basically I would like to know what a good framework is for creating applications(mostly Windows, but wouldn't hurt if it would be cross platform) that would allow to do fancy GUI **animations**, **transitions** and is easily **modifiable**.
I worked with the swing library for java so far. Its a solid GUI library but its completely static.

Here an examples for showing off what I mean: Atom.io 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

QT is an excellent choice for app and UI development.  The API is C++ (though many other bindings are available) and it has a solid IDE and UI building.  It is free to use for non-commercial work.  https://www.qt.io/